# Redshift: Simple query is leading to nested loop join

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using a query to fetch the number of rows deleted for a given queryid:

```
select stl_delete.query,
       listagg(distinct svv_table_info.table,',')
from stl_delete
join svv_table_info on svv_table_info.table_id=stl_delete.tbl
where stl_delete.query=1090750
group by stl_delete.query
```

The result seems correct.

When I run:

select event,solution from stl_alert_event_log where query = pg_last_query_id();

```
event                              solution
================================== ======================================================
Nested Loop Join in the query plan Review the join predicates to avoid Cartesian products
```

Firstly, why is there nested loop?

How do I fix the nested loop join here? Going through the internet, solution is the join predicate which is present in the query.

Even if I remove the listaggr and group by, I still see the issue:

```
select stl_delete.query,
       svv_table_info.table
from stl_delete
join svv_table_info on svv_table_info.table_id=stl_delete.tbl
where stl_delete.query=1090750
```

Comment: What are the data types?   Why do you have columns with names like `query` and `ttbl`? Those names are just confusing.

Comment: The GROUP BY/LISTAGG?

Comment: Prepend each column with the table (or table alias) to clearly identify where it's coming from.

Comment: query is a column in svv_table_info (system view), I have aliased it as t (see my query)

Comment: I have edited my query to add table names with each column name

Comment: Even removing the group by and listaggr still has the nested loop problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system view svv_table_info is complex and gather a lot of information about tables most of which you are not using.  The loop join is inside this view and is needed to produce the in-depth table report.

Your query just needs the name of the table based on tableid.  There is a system table that holds this information and will run quicker and not produce a loop join.  pg_class has the tableid in a column called oid and the table name in relname.  (FYI if you select * from pg_class oid won't show up, you need to specify it by name)

Or you can just live with the alert.  This loop join isn't very big in Redshift terms.